# I would like to enable inside function import in type script how should I do it?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, typeorm

I use typescript and typeorm, have fellow error for command:

```
typeorm migration:run
```

errors:

```
F:\personalprojects\MyProject\src\entity\User.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
     "es5",
     "es6"
  ],
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "outDir": "./build",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "sourceMap": true
}
}
```

My User.ts is:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
firstName: string;

@Column()
lastName: string;

@Column()
age: number;

}
```

how to enable inside the function can import something?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to enable inside function import in type script how should I do it?

Your tsconfig and `user.ts` code is correct. It is the correct way to import in typescript.

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Your `typeorm migration:run` command is trying to execute TypeScript in a *JavaScript* environment without transpiling. AKA the build is setup incorrectly and should give out JS before running it.

## Fix

Your typeorm setup is incorrect. E.g. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2155 < similar error due to bad typeorm project config.

Comment: what is meaning of "AKA the build is setup" incorrectly? what is AKA? How to correct set up?

Comment: You mean I should translate the ts entity to js and then the typeorm migration:run can work?